# How to install python2.7 specific packages on Arch Linux?

Tags: python-2.7, archlinux

I am building an Arch Linux system from scratch, and presently there is no Python in the system. I could install Python2.7 by using this command:

```
pacman -S python2
```

But when I try to install some package for python like this:

```
pacman -S python-numpy
```

Pacman only shows option to download Python3.x and numpy for Python3.x. There is no other option available. How can I make sure that when I search for Python stuff, it only searches based on which Python version I have installed? There is no Python3 in my system and I have no need of it at all. In my Ubuntu system, I do not specify the Python version but it is always taken care of. I have no clue how to handle this in Arch Linux.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Arch Linux the default Python version is 3, so all python-* packages (including python itself) are for Python3.  Fortunately Python2 is still fully supported, they are just prefixed with python2-* instead.  So to install numpy you would do `pacman -S python2-numpy`.

Comment: there is no python2-pip anymore

Answer (score 8):

Also if you want to download the packages specific to python2.7 from Python Package Index you'll have to use pip2.
e.g.:

```
sudo pip2 install <package name>
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I have been doing lately. Thanks for the response! The python2-packagename usually works for the packages that have a long list of external dependencies. Many other popular packages (e.g., matplotlib, polygon, etc.) do not have standalone packages of their own.

Comment: @SubhamoySengupta So, how did you proceed for these other packages?

Comment: Be careful though that this will leave you with two package managers that don't know each other. Package conflicts might happen.